# Removing specific characters from a nested list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists which looks like `[[text],[text],['', ''], ['', ''],[text]]`

I've tried

```
list3 = list2
[x for x in list2 if not '['', '']' in x]
```

but the list still remain. I just need to remove the `['', ''], ['', '']` so I can iterate over the entire list without getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ll = [['text'],['text'],['', ''], ['', ''],['text']]
result = []

for inner_list in ll:
  if all(inner_list):
    result.append(inner_list)

print(result)
```

**RESULT**

```
[['text'], ['text'], ['text']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a string eequals list check which will always return false. You can either do a full list equality check or a contains check.

```
[x for x in players2 if [","] != x]
```

Or

```
[x for x in players2 if "," not in x]
```

Comment: it's actually a list containing two empty string separated by a ,

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by fixing your list selector code:

```
[x for x in list if not ',' in x]
```